# Можно ли в LocalStorage хранить js/css/html данные?

Tags: html5, localstorage

Возможно ли хранить в LocalStorage хранить js/css/html данные, чтоб при каждой перезагрузке их не тягать?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

А зчаем изобретать велосипед? Кэш давно реализован во всех браузерах без ухищрений с `localStorage`. Если URL и хэш файла на сервере не меняются, и вы не шлёте в хедерах [явный запрет](http://www.mobify.com/blog/beginners-guide-to-http-cache-headers/) на кэширование ресурсов, эти ресурсы сохранятся в кэше и при обновлении страницы будут подтягиваться из него. Также кэш, в отличие от `localStorage`, меньше ограничен в объёме, браузер может закэшировать хоть весь статический контент вашего сайта, в то время как в `localStorage` помещается всего [2.5-10 МБ](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2989284/what-is-the-max-size-of-localstorage-values) данных.

Comment: А еще можно пользоваться популярными CDN для популярных скриптов, тогда есть шанс, что скрипт уже будет закэширован при первой загрузке сайта.

Answer (score 4):

Да, в localStorage можно хранить любые текстовые данные объёмом до 5 МБ. При превышении этого объёма браузер запросит у пользователя разрешение на увеличение квоты.

Только зачем? Лучше нормально настроить заголовки кэширования, либо даже использовать кэш-манифест для создания оффлайн-приложения.

Если появилась идея частичного обновления стилей и скриптов (т. е. с сервера приходит дифф, а скрипт это дело мёрджит), то Яндекс отказался от этого подхода из-за ухудшения скорости загрузки и появления сложностей в разработке.